# Is there a Java library to load data from a WFS server?

Tags: web-mapping, java, wfs, gml

I am writing a java client to display remote GIS data. I want to load data provided in GML by a WFS server. Do you know a java library I could use for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoTools: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTDOC/WFS+Plugin